# How to use a localized "short format" when formatting dates in Django?

Tags: python, django, date-format

I need to display a localized formatted date. If I use django.utils.formats.localize, the date is returned as "June 11, 2012". How could I format the date as to return "06/11/2012", with proper localization (e.g., "11/06/2012 in UK)?

I need something similar to Java's [DateFormat.SHORT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html). Is there something analogous to that?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, there is [SHORT_DATE_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SHORT_DATE_FORMAT).

In a template, it is possible to use it with the [date filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date):

```
{{ your_date_value|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }}
```

Outside of a template, it is possible to use `django.utils.formats.date_format`, as so:

```
from django.utils.formats import date_format
date_format(date_obj, format='SHORT_DATE_FORMAT', use_l10n=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! As I'm not using a template (I'm serializing the date to JSON for viewing in a chart), I had to dig through Django's source to find django.utils.formats.date_format, which takes SHORT_DATE_FORMAT as a possible format value, fulfilling my need.

Comment: @Wilerson, would you care to post your comment as an alternative answer with an example? I did exactly the same thing on my own because I didn't notice your comment. Thanks in advance :)!

Comment: @mrts I have edited in my usage of the function at the accepted answer.

Comment: @jipic It works fine, but I am wondering, why the language is not detected automatically?!!