# Django + AJAX comments

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I'm trying to implement a comment system without reloading the page, but it doesn't work. Comments are inserted only after the page is reloaded, but AJAX does not work.

```
       <!-- COMMENT -->
    <div class="comment-section">
        <form action="{% url 'love:comment_urls' %}" method="POST" class='comment-form'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value={{i.pk}}>
            {{ comment_form }}
            <button type="submit" name="submit_c_form">
                Опубликовать
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <hr>

    <div class="comment_set">
        {% if i.quotes_comment.all %}
        {% for com in i.quotes_comment.all %}
        <b>{{ com.user }}:</b>
        {{ com.body }}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

JS code

```
 // COMMENT 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.comment-form').submit(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log($(this).serialize());
        var url = $(this).attr('action')
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log('Заработало')
                $('.comment-section').html(response['form']);
            },
            error: function (rs, error) {
                console.log(rs, error)

            }
        })

    })
})
```

```
@csrf_exempt
def create_comment(request):
profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)

data = json.loads(request.body)
post_id = data['post_id']
body = data['body']

comment_form = CommentModelForm(data)

if comment_form.is_valid():
    print('Form is valid')
    instance = comment_form.save(commit=False)
    instance.user = profile
    instance.quotes = QuotesHonors.objects.get(
        id=post_id)
    instance.save()
    comment_form = CommentModelForm()

    return JsonResponse({
        'content': body
    })
    
return redirect("love:home_urls")
```

As I said, comments are inserted only after a reboot, but when I click publish, nothing happens. If you change the dataType to 'json', the parser error pops up. Can you explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're just posting the new comment, but you're not getting new comments from API. Another alternative would be to add the comment into your HTML from your AJAX code, only if the POST request you're making returns a status code of __201__ or __200__ (I don't know which status code your API returns upon creation, should be 201 btw).

Comment: Three questions: 1) Is `Заработало` displayed in the console? 2) What do you get when you log `response` and `response['form']` to the console? 3) Are you sure you want to replace html contents of `$(".comment-section")`, and not `$(".comment_set")` ?

Comment: @ccolin, To be honest, I do not know Js, so I am unlikely to be able to do what you say without a clear example. The code being executed is 200

Comment: @FiddlingAway, ) Yes, it works

2) When 'response', AJAX is triggered, that is, the page is not reloaded, but all the HTML contained in the response is inserted into the comment. When 'response['form']' , the code works, but you need to reload the page so that a new comment is displayed.
3) I'm not sure about that. I need everything to work. And I do not know what to replace comment-section or comment-set for this

Comment: OK, let's try it like this. Should all the new comments you get from the AJAX response go into this elment - `<div class="comment_set">` ? If they should, you could do one of these two things. If your AJAX is returning just the new comments, use `$(".comment_set").append(response['form'])`. If your AJAX is returning all of the comments, then you can use `$(".comment_set").html(response['form'])`.

Comment: @FiddlingAway, still not working. throws an error "error" and 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Error 500 is a back-end error. Did you change anything there? The things I suggested should have gone inside the `success` part of your `$.ajax`.

Comment: @FiddlingAway, ok, the error is gone (my omission), but it's the same as before: it is impossible to leave a comment without reloading the page. Another interesting thing: how many times do I click on the "publish" button, how many times will the comment be published after the reboot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250910/discussion-between-fiddlingaway-and-h-g).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say what you are doing wrong overall there is code missing. But from what you shared, `csrf_token` is not in AJAX request `header`. And mainly, by using [JQuery .serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/), you are trying to pass data in URL-encoded notation and not as a JSON object.

This `.serialize()` output would be used to pass data as a query string by appending it to a base URL. And, at the view accessing it with `request.GET.get('parameter')`. Instead, what we want is to pass data as `JSON` and access it through `request.body` at view level.

Here is a full example:

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=timezone.now())

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    body = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments', blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=timezone.now())
```

urls.py

```
from .views import post_detail, comment_create

app_name = 'love'

urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:pk>/', post_detail, name='post-detail'),
    path('comment/create/', comment_create, name='comment-create'),
]
```

Two views, one to render the template and another to handle the AJAX request. The tricky part was trying to find a way to [format date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10989954/7100120) in the same way as the template.

views.py

```
from django.utils.formats import date_format
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=pk)
    has_commented = post.comments.filter(user=request.user).exists()

    context = {
        'post': post,
        'has_commented': has_commented
    }

    return render(request, 'post_detail.html', context)

def comment_create(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    post_id = data['post_id']
    comment_body = data['body']
    
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)
    comment = Comment.objects.create(
        user=request.user, 
        body=comment_body, 
        post=post
    )

    created_at = date_format(comment.created_at, format='M. d, Y, h:m a', use_l10n=True)

    return JsonResponse({
        'user': comment.user.username, 
        'body': comment.body, 
        'created_at': created_at
        })
```

In this first template part we just display data, note that `{# % if not has_commented % #}` is commented out, when first writing the code I limited the number comments to one per `User`.

post_detail.html (HTML & DTL):

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
    <h4>{{post.created_at}}</h4>
    <p>{{post.body}}</p>

    <hr>

    <div id="comment-div">
        {# % if not has_commented % #}
            <form action="{% url 'love:comment-create' %}" id="comment-form">
                <input type="hidden" id="post-id" value="{{post.id}}">
                <textarea id="comment-body" maxlength="255" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" id="submit-comment">Comment</button>
            </form>
            <hr>
        {# % endif % #}
    </div>

    <div id="comment-list">
        <h2> Comments </h2>
        {% if post.comments.all %}
            {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
                <p>At {{comment.created_at|date:"M. d, Y, h:m a"}} {{comment.user}} commented:</p> 
                <p>{{comment.body}}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

This second part, containing the `<script>` is responsible for every event in the template after adding a new comment. The first function is used to [retrieve csrftoken value from cookies](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/csrf/#using-csrf-protection-with-ajax).

Then, on `submit` click we collect data and send the AJAX request. Attention to a few lines. First, where [csrf header name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#csrf-header-name) is set `headers: {'X-CsrfToken': csrftoken}`. Second, where data is [converted to JSON string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) `data: JSON.stringify({ post_id: post_id, body: body })`.

post_detail.html (JS):

```
    <script>
        function getCookie(name) {
            let cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
                const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }

        $('#submit-comment').click( function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $('#comment-form').attr("action");
            var post_id = $('#post-id').attr("value");
            var body = $('#comment-body').val();
            const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: url,
                headers: {'X-CsrfToken': csrftoken},
                data: JSON.stringify({ post_id: post_id, body: body }),
                success: function(comment) {
                    // $('#comment-div').prop("hidden", true);
                    $('#comment-body').val('');
                    $('#comment-list').append(
                        `<p>At ${comment.created_at} ${comment.user} commented:</p> 
                        <p>${comment.body}</p>`
                    );
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Lastly, on success, clear body input and update the template by appending data to `<div id="comment-list">`. To limit to one comment per user, uncomment `$('#comment-div').prop("hidden", true);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but now everything is working a little weird. Firstly, I can leave a comment only under the first post so that AJAX works. If you leave a comment in other posts, the JSONDecodeError error is called: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0).
Secondly, when I leave a certain comment, it begins to be duplicated absolutely in all other comments. And only after the page is reloaded, everything becomes as before and a comment is added to the first post.

Comment: Are you using my code or adapting to yours? Because my templates and views are working smoothly. I noticed that to create a `Post` it is required to have a `Comment` related, so I will update the model on my answer and remove that limitation.

Comment: I'm trying to adapt mine. But the differences are only in the connection between Post and Comment - I have a ForeignKey. Therefore, the view is a little different. But it seems that I completely confused everything in my code, so I'll try to write everything from scratch. Thanks for the answer, at least it works

Comment: I see, it does make sense. I will rework the answer as soon as I can. Just remember to share more code to avoid this kind of situation :)

Comment: Just minor changes at `models.py` and the ajax function at `views.py`, to correctly handle the new relation. Everything else remains the same.